# Django group by in many to many relationships

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model named Evaluation with following schema:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
value = models.IntegerField()
```

The value field will take value in 0,1,2,3.

Now I want to get the count of evaluations of a given user with each value. For example, suppose my data are:

```
user.id | value
1       | 0
1       | 0
1       | 1
1       | 2
1       | 3
1       | 3
```

I want to get the result

```
value | count
0     | 2
1     | 1
2     | 1
3     | 2
```

I use the query

```
Evaluation.objects.filter(user=request.user).annotate(count=Count('value')).order_by('value')
```

But it does not return the correct answer. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
Evaluation.objects.filter(user=request.user).values('value').annotate(count=Count('value')).order_by('value')
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `values()` method:

```
Evaluation.objects.filter(user_id=request.user) \
                  .values('value').annotate(count=Count('value')) \
                  .order_by('value')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build **reverse query** and query the `User` model instead:

```
User.objects.filter(user=request.user).values('evaluation__value').annotate(count=Count('evaluation__user'))
```

which will produce below results:

```
[{'count': 1, 'evaluation__value': 1}, {'count': 1, 'evaluation__value': 2}, {'count': 2, 'evaluation__value': 0}, {'count': 2, 'evaluation__value': 3}]
```

Additionally you might want to sort the results:

```
queryset.order_by('-count')  # sorts by count desc
```

Unfortunately you cannot alias the value in `values` queryset method hence the ugly `evaluation__value` as field name. [See this Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16735).

HTH.